# How to snapshot test with jest and RTKquery?

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, react-redux, jestjs

I'm bothering with it couple days. My goal is to snapshot screen/component but I'm stuck.
I have to use `jest snapshot` and the library `react redux toolkit query`.
In the `ContactScreen` are rendered data of contact office depending on which user is logged in. So if you want to see office data first of all you must logged in and after that there's two endpoints getting `office_id` and second endpoint using `office_id` to get all data about office.

`ContactScreen-test.js`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { useGetUserDataQuery, useGetOfficeDataQuery } from '../../services';

import ContactScreen from '../../screens/ContactScreen';

jest.mock('../../services', () => ({
  useGetUserDataQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("fc5bf89b-6df8-4831-8f56-d08bb6a8d728")
}));

// "office_id": "fc5bf89b-6df8-4831-8f56-d08bb6a8d728"

it('returns the mocked office_id', async () => {
  const office_id = await useGetUserDataQuery();  // Run the function
  expect(office_id).toEqual('fc5bf89b-6df8-4831-8f56-d08bb6a8d728');  // Make an assertion on the result
});

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const snap = renderer.create(<ContactScreen />).toJSON();
  expect(snap).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

After running test error appear which is according to two files `services.ts` and `ContactScreen.tsx`

`error file`

```
TypeError: (0 , _services.useGetOfficeDataQuery) is not a function

      17 |
      18 |   const { data: userData } = useGetUserDataQuery();
    > 19 |   const { data: contact } = useGetOfficeDataQuery(userData?.office_id);
         |                             ^
      20 |
      21 |   const OfficeAdress = () => {
      22 |     return (
```

`services.ts`

```
[...]

export const callApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'link to api call',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.access_token;

      if (device_id) {
        headers.set('Device_Id', device_id);
        headers.set('Authorization', `${token}`);
      }
      return headers;
    }
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    login: builder.mutation<UserResponse, LoginRequest>({
      query: data => ({
        url: '/sessions',
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      })
    }),
    getUserData: builder.query({
      query: (arg: void) => ({ url: `users/me/`, body: arg })
    }),
    getOfficeData: builder.query({
      query: (office_id: string) => ({ url: `office_contacts/${office_id}` })
    })
  })
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useGetOfficeDataQuery, useGetUserDataQuery } =
  callApi;
```

`ContactScreen.tsx`

```
const ContactScreen = () => {
  const [isLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Poppins-Medium': require('../../assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.otf'),
    'Poppins-Regular': require('../../assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.otf')
  });

  const { data: userData } = useGetUserDataQuery();
  const { data: contact } = useGetOfficeDataQuery(userData?.office_id);

  const OfficeAdress = () => {
    return (
      <Text>
        {t('contact.shortcutStreet')} {contact?.street} {contact?.house_number}{' '}
        {contact?.room_number}
        {'\n'}
        {contact?.zip_code} {contact?.city}
      </Text>
    );
  };

  const OfficeAdressMap =
    'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' +
    `${contact?.street} ${contact?.house_number} ${contact?.room_number} ${contact?.zip_code} ${contact?.city}`;

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.officeNameContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.officeName}>{contact?.name}</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>{t('contact.address')}</Text>
          <View style={styles.informationContainer}>
            <View style={styles.icons}>
              <ContactIcon name="map-marker-outline" />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                Linking.openURL(OfficeAdressMap);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.informationText}>
                <OfficeAdress />
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late for Mikołaj Wittbrodt, but I landed here looking for answers to the same question, so I'll share what I've found.

Basically, we're wrapping the test with a store provider, and mocking the RTK Query hook. See my [minimal sandbox example.](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/laughing-star-n7pkph?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A17%2C5)

Key elements:

- `setupStore` function in store.js to enable creating a mock store for tests. (This is not strictly necessary, but definitely convenient.)
- `renderWithProviders` in setupTests.js to wrap the test components with a provider.
- `jest.mock(...useGetProductsQuery...)` in the test file to mock the RTK query hook.

Based on [blog post by Remarkable Mark](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2023/03/28/how-to-test-redux-toolkit-query/). This post doesn't demonstrate the use of snapshots, but it provides the solution to the error mentioned in this question.